# Sharing Office Online Excel Scripts

Tags: excel, office365, office-scripts

I have an Excel script created in my Office Online account. I see where I can share that script with another user per workbook and also where I can share the script with another user as a whole in the manage access section of the .osts file itself.

I need the script to be accessible to an entire user - not just per workbook - so I've shared the .osts file with the second user.

That user can see the file in their shared files, but if they open an Excel file, it is not listed in their scripts. How do we get the shared .osts file to appear in the Automate tab when they open any workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, Excel only shows the scripts that are either (a) present in user's own OneDrive folder (documents/Office Scripts) or the ones shared on the workbook. We are working on enabling SharePoint based storage that you can use to share with everyone on the team and users can open it from their taskpane. For now though, the scripts can only be shared in the Excel workbook level.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now allows scripts to be saved in SharePoint so that other users of the SharePoint site can access them. [Script-storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/script-storage)